# Can I Host .NET 2.0 Running Web Application with .NET 4.0 App Pool

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7

Can I Host .NET 2.0 Running web Application with .NET 4.0 App Pool..??

I have added the following node in the Web.config of my Web Application :

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
</startup>
```

This means that my application runs using .NET 2.0 CLR.

I added it to an Application in ISS with App Pool set to .NET 4.0 and did a quick smoke test. Its working fine for normal cases.

Refer the image below. The name of the application is LMSInterface.

[image]

Will it run seamlessly..?? Or are there any hidden complexities / issues in doing so..??

Answer (score 1):

It could be done:

```
Project framework 2.0 can run in IIS with Application pool 4.0
```

Here's my Test:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to remove your support run time at your web config file. In my sample i don't have it. I'll just publish the project by .Net Framework 2.0 and try to run it in IIS application pool 4.0 according to your problem but fortunately it is running without any problem.

Comment: For additional cases "Install a framework 2.0 at your server".